# devExpress, how to dock gridView to the panel and remove 'drag column header'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, gridview, devexpress

I cannot dock fill gridView to the panel in DevExpress Visual Studio 2010, I cannot remove "drag column header..." as well, both are visible on the screenshot.
Can somebody help me with those issue?!
[image]

part of the code:`EntityConnection entityConn = new EntityConnection(Utility.GetEntityConnection("ViEFConn"));

```
List<Object> myList = new List<Object>();

//GridControl gridcon = new GridControl();

using (ViEFConn dbF = new ViEFConn(entityConn))
{
    // LINQ join query
    var query = from f in db.Fields
                          join t in db.Types
                          on f.TYPE_ID
                          equals t.TYPE_ID
                          where (f.ASS_TYPE == _assType)
                          select new
                          {
                              f.NAME,
                              f.FIELD ,
                              t.DATA,
                              f.TEXT,                            
                          };                              

    // add linq query to the list
    myList.AddRange(query);
    // bind data source of grid control to the list
    AssignmentDetailsGridControl.DataSource = myList;

    gridView1.OptionsBehavior.Editable = true;
    SaveButton.Enabled = true;
    SaveCloseButton.Enabled = true;

    AssignmentDetailsGridControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    gridView1.OptionsCustomization.AllowColumnMoving = false;
    gridView1.OptionsView.ShowGroupPanel = false; `
```

Comment: To dock grid control: `gridCONTROL.Dock = full` To disable grouping  panel: `gridVIEW.OptionsView.ShowGridPanel = false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dock your grid you need to set

```
GridControl.Dock = DockStyleFill
```

Note: it is property of `GridControl`, not `GridView`.

It is not quite clear what do you mean by `remove "drag column header..."`.

If you want to disable dragging columns you need to set property

```
GridView.OptionsCustomization.AllowColumnMoving = false
```

If you want to disable group panel (marked by arrow on your screenshot) you need to set

```
GridView.OptionsView.ShowGroupPanel = false
```

Comment: AssignmentDetailsGridControl.Dock=DockStyle.Fill;                   gridView1.OptionsCustomization.AllowColumnMoving = false;
gridView1.OptionsView.ShowGroupPanel = false; I have used above without error but it still didn't do any job, What the reason can be?

Comment: @richardpawel It's hard to make assumptions about what you're doing wrong without seeing your actual code, not only these properties setting. Please, update your question with more expanded sample of your code.

Comment: there was a problem with connection, it is sorted now. I will try now to use your hints, if they will work I will mark your answer as correct. thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the Grouppanel with

```
gridview1.optionsview.showgrouppanel = false;
```

For remove the right empty area you have to set

```
dockstyle = fill
```

or you can place DevExpress LayoutControl at first. Set this to docktype=fill and place the grid on the layout control (thats recommended by DevExpress!).

At least make sure you havent place an emptyspaceitem at the right sight.